# Class not autoloading?

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I've got an autoloader function in my application:

```
 spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'library'  . DS . 'intranet'  . DS  . 'classes' . DS .strtolower($className) . '.php')){
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'library'  . DS . 'intranet'  . DS  . 'classes' . DS .strtolower($className) . '.php');
    print_r($className." loaded <br/>");
} else if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'controller' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php')) {
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'controller' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php');
} else if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'model' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php')) {
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'model' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php');
} else if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'view' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php')) {
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'view' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php');
} else {
    throw new Exception("Class: $className not autoloaded!");
}
});
```

In one of my files, a session manager, it calls a class called database. The `database` class has not been called before, and should then at that point be autoloaded.

However, it appears to be not - that said, I'm printing out a list of classes which are being loaded:

```
debug loaded 
sessionmanager loaded 
database loaded 
database loaded
```

So it looks like it's being loaded, right?

In the sessionnmanager class:

```
Fatal error: Class 'database' not found
```

Does my autoloader look fine?

I've put a print in the database class in the `__construct` method, yep, sure enough, it is being called.

Comment: Isit possible you have two database files and because of the conflict the autoloader is loading the wrong file one?

Comment: There shouldn't be, but I've looked and there's only one in the project.

Comment: Did you check your library/intranet/classes/database.php file? Does it contain declaration of class "database"? Seems that not.

Comment: @ElenaSharovar the application is working perfectly fine locally. `/library/intranet/classes/database.php` exists and only contains one declaration

Comment: Hmm.. but if file exists, and is successfully included, there can be only one problem - there's no "class database" declaration there. Very strange issue.

Comment: I'd agree with you. If I remove the contents of the database class file, then it goes mental and everything else breaks.

Comment: You should never trow exceptions in autoloaders, because if you (or a library you use) register another one, it will never get called.

Comment: @KingCrunch true, I've replaced it with a debug function.